# Closures not working gives errors function name should be string

Tags: php, function, closures, anonymous

I have Created a  closure function but can not access it from the view page.Anyone please help.Thanks in advance.

My function is :

```
$ph = function($labelid)
{
    return Model_Label::_ph($labelid);
};

View::set_global('ph', $ph);
```

I have called this function form view page like this

```
echo $ph('main_menu:hello'));
```